# Why PowerShell will treat dot ( . ) different than Command Prompt?

Tags: powershell, maven, command-prompt

Here is a simple command:

```
echo -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes
```

When running in the **Command Prompt**, the output will be:

```
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes
```

[image]

When running in the **PowerShell**, the output will be:

```
-DarchetypeGroupId=org
.apache.maven.archetypes
```

[image]

When running in the **PowerShell** with `echo.exe` command:

```
echo.exe -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes
```

The output will be:

```
-DarchetypeGroupId=org .apache.maven.archetypes
```

[image]

The tiny different will cause me unable to run many commands when using Apache Maven CLI in the PowerShell environment. Such as:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.baeldung -DartifactId=parent-project -B
```

I can't find out what's the main reason cause for this issue in PowerShell. Does anyone know what's the language feature on PowerShell cause this issue?

Comment: "The tiny different will cause me unable to run many commands when using Apache Maven CLI in the PowerShell environment." - please show us some sample commands that are impacted by this.

Comment: Here is the example: `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.baeldung -DartifactId=parent-project -B`

Comment: You're seeing a bug, unfortunately. _Quote_ your arguments to work around it, e.g.: `'-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes'` The linked duplicate shows other workarounds and links to the relevant bug reports on GitHub.